# In AutoCompleteTextview Suggestion list overlaps keyboard or goes above AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

[image]I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` which displays name. When I scroll the suggestions, the suggestions list will not stay between `AutoCompleteTextView` and android soft keyboard, sometimes it will move above my `AutoCompleteTextView` and sometimes it overlaps android soft keyboard. Please help me solve this issue

Comment: can you share screenshot of problem?

Comment: @HemantParmar please check now

Comment: try this `android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-30dp"`